# How to change URL based on option selected so that the new url will go to page with that option pre-selected?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

For instance if I have a page with two options and I click option on option two. I want to create a new url where option 2 has already been selected.

```
 <select>
  <option>Opttion 1</option>
  <option >Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple you can use URL Search params for that. [URL Search Params](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) can for example look like this `yourlocation.com/?param1=value` param1, in that case, will be your parameter and value is its value.

You can read the param value through javascript like so:

```
let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
let selectedOption = params.get("option");
console.log(selectedOption);
```

For your example you can change the HTML Code like so:

```
<select>
  <option id="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option id="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

and add some javascript:

```
let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
let selectedOption = params.get("option");

document
  .getElementById("option" + selectedOption)
  .setAttribute("selected", true);
```

This code will set the selected Option to the one in the search query.